# SQL Query to retrieve single record per filter

Tags: sql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT min(salesorder.SOM_SalesOrderID) AS salesorder,
    Item.IMA_ItemID,
    Item.IMA_ItemName,
    Customer.CUS_CorpName,
    WK.WKO_WorkOrderID,
    min(WK.WKO_OrigRequiredDate),
    WK.WKO_WorkOrderTypeCode,
    min(WK.WKO_RequiredDate),
    max(WK.WKO_LastWorkDate),
    min(wk.WKO_RequiredQty),
    wk.WKO_MatlIssueDate,
    min(SalesOrderDelivery.SOD_RequiredQty),
    Item.IMA_ItemTypeCode,
    Item.IMA_OnHandQty,
    min(SalesOrderDelivery.SOD_PromiseDate),
    min(WO.woo_operationseqID) AS seqid
FROM SalesOrder
INNER JOIN SalesOrderLine ON SalesOrder.SOM_RecordID = SalesOrderLine.SOI_SOM_RecordID
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDelivery ON SalesOrderLine.SOI_RecordID = SalesOrderDelivery.SOD_SOI_RecordID,
    WO.
INNER JOIN Item ON SalesOrderLine.SOI_IMA_RecordID = Item.IMA_RecordID
INNER JOIN WKO wk ON Item.IMA_ItemID = WK.WKO_ItemID
INNER JOIN Customer ON SalesOrder.SOM_CUS_RecordID = Customer.CUS_RecordID
INNER JOIN woo WO ON WO.WOO_WorkOrderID = WK.WKO_WorkOrderID
WHERE wk.WKO_StatusCode = 'Released'
    AND WO.WOO_StatusCode IS NULL
    AND SalesOrderDelivery.SOD_ShipComplete = 'false'
GROUP BY WK.WKO_WorkOrderID,
    Item.IMA_ItemID,
    Item.IMA_ItemName,
    Customer.CUS_CorpName,
    WK.WKO_WorkOrderTypeCode,
    wk.WKO_MatlIssueDate,
    Item.IMA_ItemTypeCode,
    Item.IMA_OnHandQty
```

I need 1 record returned for each wk.wko_workorderid. There is a field that is not included that I'm not sure how to get. I need to retrieve the woo.woo_workcenterid that corresponds to min(WO.woo_operationseqID)as seqid. I cannot include it in the general query since there are multiple workcenterids in the table and I only want the specific one that is part of the min operation sequence record.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When it comes out of a query designer, probably.

Comment: I love the co-mingling of two character abbreviations with full words and random case.  HOWEVER, that's not why we're here is it?

Comment: You can do a RANK CTE where you get the first woo.woo_workcenterid ordered by the sequence record.  OR you can have a join to another query of that same table where you can get the woo.woo_workcenterid.

Comment: @GolezTrol: now that it has been edited it is indeed quite readable (look at the edit history right after it was posted)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see.